# Почему запрос ничего не выводит?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    product.title,
    stock,
    price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.title, ': ', pv.value SEPARATOR ', ') property_values
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_property_value pv ON pv.product_id = product.id
INNER JOIN property p ON p.id = pv.property_id
  AND (p.code = 'color' AND pv.value = 'Красный')
  AND (p.code = 'width' AND (pv.value = 4 OR pv.value = 5))
  AND (p.code = 'height' AND pv.value = 5)
GROUP BY product.id;
```

[Полный DDL с данными](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/833b8f/596). Что я делаю не так? Пробовал и через `ON` и через `WHERE`, но ничего не выводит...

Comment: вероятно потому что вы не понимаете разницу между AND и OR

Comment: вы хотите выбрать товарыны, которые одновременно имеют три этих характеристики?

Comment: @teran смешно. Да, все три

Comment: чего смешного? очевидно, `p.code = 'color' AND p.code=  "width"` всегда будет равно false

Comment: если вам нужны все три характеристики, то выберите из свойств такие продукты, чтобы число строк равнялось трем по указанным параметрам. То есть условия через OR и having count = 3

Comment: @teran не подумал об этом... Но как же правильно? Я не понял как поможет having. Можете показать конечный запрос?(

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите =( Я правда уже несколько часов над этим думаю. Прямо неразрешимая загадка. Если бы на ПХП делал поставил бы несколько `if` подряд, а в sql хз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, так.

```
SELECT pr.id
     , pr.title
     , GROUP_CONCAT(p.code, ': ', ppv.value separator ', ' ) AS props
FROM product_property_value  AS ppv
INNER JOIN property AS p ON (
  ppv.property_id = p.id 
  AND (
      (p.code = 'color' AND ppv.value = 'Красный')
      OR (p.code = 'width' AND (ppv.value = 4 OR ppv.value = 5))
      OR (p.code = 'height' AND ppv.value = 5)
    )
)
INNER JOIN product AS pr ON pr.id = ppv.product_id 
GROUP BY pr.id, pr.title
HAVING count(pr.id) = 3;
```

выбираем все товары, совпадающие по каждому свойству, а потом после группировки оставляем только товары, где присутствуют все 3.

Comment: О, наконец-то. Спасибо!!! Вроде работает правильно!

Comment: А можете объяснить для чего там `MIN`?

Comment: а не для  чего,  уберите )